# Compilation Error "String does not name a type"

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I am getting the error "string does not name a type" despite having the "using namespace std;" in the program.

```
#ifndef SHAPE_H
#define SHAPE_H

using namespace std;

class Shape
{
    public:
        Shape();
        virtual ~Shape();
        string getShapeName();
        void setShapeName(string shapeName);
        virtual float calculateArea() = 0; //Calculates area of the shape
    protected:
        const float PI = 3.14159265;
    private:
        string m_ShapeName;

};

#endif // SHAPE_H_INCLUDED
```

Comment: You missed to `#include <string>`. And please don't use `using namespace std;` especially not in header files.

Comment: Hi @πάντα ῥεῖ, thank you very much for the advice, I made the changes as per the advice and program is compiling.Can you please elaborate, as to why it is a bad idea to use namespaces?

Comment: Sure: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `<string>` header:

```
#include <string>
```